# Android webview.loadUrl works with one URL GET string but not Another

Tags: android, get, webview, cgi

I am new at Java and Android so thank for you help.

I wrote a simple Android WebView app to view my home webcam.  I can get webview to return a snapshot of the webcam but not send controls to pan etc.

The line that works is

webview.loadUrl("http://myhost.com/snapshot.cgi?user=myusername&pwd=mypassword");

This works and returns a snapshot of my current webcam a FOSCAM

This line DOES NOT WORK!

webview.loadUrl("http://myhost.com/decoder_control.cgi?command=28?user=myusername&pwd=mypassword");

The above line uses that same username / password but returns a HTTP 401 Unauthorized error

WHAT is going on.. they both work fine in a browser? and in CURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the second question mark... Why is that there? I imagine it should be an ampersand unless you have some weird protocol.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me.. Thanks for helping an newbeeee

Comment: No problem. Just mark the answer as accepted or your accepted percentage will not stay at 100%.